# Is the Cartan permanent odd for finite global dimension?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Define the Cartan permanent of a finite dimensional algebra as the permanent of the Cartan matrix. 
Is the Cartan permanent of a finite dimensional algebra with finite global dimension always an odd integer?
This is true for acyclic quiver algebras and experiments suggest that it is also true for all Nakayama algebras.

Comment: Modulo 2 the determinant and permanent are the same, or what do I miss?

Comment: A theorem of Eilenberg asserts that the Cartan determinant of a finite-dimensional algebra of finite global dimension is equal to $\pm 1$. Hence determinant and permanent are congruent to $1$ modulo $2$. The reference is S. Eilenberg, Algebras of cohomologically finite dimension, Comment. Math. Helv. 28 (1958), 310–319.

Comment: @PhilippLampe  Thanks (also to Fedor Petrov), can you turn this into an answer? I was aware that the cartan determinant is either 1 or -1 for finite global dimension (this can be for example also be found in the textbook of assem, simson and skowronski), but I was too blind to see the easy mod 2 argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A theorem of Eilenberg asserts that the Cartan determinant of a finite-dimensional algebra of finite global dimension is equal to $\pm 1$. Hence the Cartan determinant and the Cartan permanent are both congruent to $1$ modulo $2$ in this situation.

The result is Proposition 21 in the following reference.

- Samuel Eilenberg, [Algebras of cohomologically finite dimension](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02566937?LI=true), Comment. Math. Helv. **28** (1954), no.1, 310--319.